# Why 8...Na6 was played in the immortal draw?

Tags: analysis, master-games

From the other question: [Is there a "perfect" game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/346/is-there-a-perfect-game) , an interesting game came up:

```
[fen ""]
[title "Hamppe-Meitner, Vienna"]

1.e4 e5 2.Nc3 Bc5 3.Na4 Bxf2+ 4.Kxf2 Qh4+ 5.Ke3 Qf4+ 6.Kd3 d5 7.Kc3 Qxe4 
8.Kb3 Na6 9.a3 Qxa4+ 10.Kxa4 Nc5+ 11.Kb4 a5+ 12.Kxc5 Ne7 13.Bb5+ Kd8 14.
Bc6 b6+ 15.Kb5 Nxc6 16.Kxc6 Bb7+ 17.Kb5 Ba6+ 18.Kc6 Bb7+ 1/2-1/2
```

My question is, why is `8...Na6` considered the best move? References to GM analysis would be great.

Stockfish says `8...Nc6` is better--in fact, `8...Na6` is not even on the top 10 recommended moves. And I can see even in the short term that the knight on c6 instead of a6 might be nice: consider `...Na5+`.

Comment: It looks like a game beginners would play.

Comment: I don't know any beginners who would play `9. ... Qxa4+` (at least with a good reason) or who would play out the rest of the game as it went (on either side).

Comment: Since it is an "Immortal" game, the players deserve to be named. This game is Hamppe-Meitner, Vienna, circa 1890 (I don't know the year by heart)

Comment: It's a pretty terrible game, to be honest.  If it was played today, nobody would give it a second look, but in the 19th century they liked flashy nonsense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I talked to National Master Dan Heisman about this game and according to him, the answer is really very simple:

At the time, black thought that `8...Na6` was the best move.  Black's intention was to control b4 and get to c5.  After that both sides played almost perfectly which resulted in a draw.

It is also possible that the game was actually made up, but this is hard to prove 140 years later.

Black probably would have played something else besides `8...Na6`, but with no computer analysis at the time, it was thought to be best.